# Best way to access the bearer token in mean/passportjs

Tags: passport.js, mean

Hey I am trying to work out where the bearer token is in a mean.io project.

I am using the default project which has Oauth enabled by default (have put the api keys in) and I can successfully log in.

How is passport storing the bearer token so I can authenticate my API calls? What is the best way to access it?

Answer (score 0):

The token that is returned by the OAuth authentication is discarded by MEAN. See https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/v0.4.4/packages/users/passport.js:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
      clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

      // accessToken and refreshToken not used, not stored.

    });
  }
));
```

You could provide your own strategies to override this behavior, or try to raise the issue with MEAN. I see you [already made a ticket](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1133). I'm afraid this may be a security consideration on their part, as there is no risk of losing the tokens if they are not stored.